# Why would someone take an address, typecast the pointer, and then dereference it?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, dereference

I ran into a weird code snippet while following an image processing guide. The language is C. What is the purpose of taking an address, casting the pointer, then dereferencing it? I am new to C, so I am unsure if this is a common practice and its purpose.

```c
unsigned char header[];

// not sure why we are dereferencing the array then getting its address and casting it into an int pointer then dereferencing that.
int width = *(int *)&header[18]; 
int height = *(int *)&header[22];
int bitDepth = *(int *)&header[28];

// why not this?
int width = (int) header[18]; 
int height = (int) header[22];
int bitDepth = (int) header[28];
```

Comment: Perhaps because `header` is an array of `unsigned char` read from a file so indexing it directly won't yield a multi-byte value.

Comment: The style is a matter of taste, but my taste differs: It *does* make little sense to index and then take the address again: `header[18]` is `*(header+18)`, so that `&header[18]` amounts to `&*(header+18)`, which is the same nonsense, just more obvious. I would write `*(int*)(header+18)`.

Comment: `&header[18]` is idiomatic: It emphasizes that `header` is a fixed array by using array indexing notation. The `+` notation suggests that you're walking through an array rather than  indexing into it. (Note also that the question title is misleading: It leaves out the cast step, which is the important part.)

Comment: The behavior of this code is not defined by the C standard because it violates the aliasing rules in C 2018 6.5 7. The current answers tell you what the author of the code may have intended to do, but code like this should not be used without a guarantee from the compiler that it supports this aliasing. You should avoid writing code like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the type of the pointer `header` is not `int *`. Maybe it has the type `void *` or `char *` or `unsigned char *`.

So to get an integer you need to cast the pointer to the type `int *` and then to dereference it to get the value pointed to by the pointer.

Comment: it is unsigned char array. Can you derefrence it, get the unsigned char, then cast that to an int? 

example: int width = (int) header[18]

Comment: @Mustafa no: the integer value is say `0x12345678` which is 4 bytes, not 1.

Comment: @Mustafa: Yes, you can do it, it is valid C, the compiler won't even warn, but it is probably not what you want.

Comment: Oh I see, bytes 18-21 are being turned into the int. Thank you.

Comment: @Mustafa In this case you will assign a single object of the type unsigned char to an integer. This does not allow to extract a whole integer.

Comment: Beware 'alignment' and 'endianness'.

Comment: @Vlad Is this actually a valid cast if no int has ever been created in that location?

Comment: At least in C++ one would have to do something like `int width = (header[18] << 3) | (header[19] << 2) | (header[20] << 1) | (header[21]);`.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica As is written in the question this code snippet is taken from a program. I can suppose that the program works as expected.:)

Comment: @Peter does C++ shift by bytes?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Which is one element in the set of undefined behavior. The Linux kernel used to call gcc with `-fnostrict-aliasing`, I think , because it does this all the time.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't understand the question (I suppose the shift code is wrong or stupid -- bother to elaborate?) I assumed that `header` is an (unsigned)  char array. Would I have to cast the elements to (unsigned) int before I shift?

Comment: @Peter it was a throwaway remark that a shift should be in bits: perhaps `int width = (header[18] << 24) | (header[19] << 16) | (header[20] << 8) | (header[21]);`

Comment: @WeatherVane Ah. Yes.

Answer (score 3):

> I am unsure if this is a common practice and its purpose.

Code like this is a problem.

**Aliasing**

> The behavior of this code is not defined by the C standard because it violates the aliasing rules in C 2018 6.5 7. (Other) answers tell you what the author of the code may have intended to do, but code like this should not be used without a guarantee from the compiler that it supports this aliasing. You should avoid writing code like this.
> [@Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75126574/why-would-someone-take-an-address-typecast-the-pointer-and-then-dereference-it#comment132573892_75126574)

**Alignment**

`(int *)&header[18]` and others risks alignment failure and *undefined behavior* (UB).  Don't do it.

**Endian**

Result is endian dependent.  Proceed with caution.

---

Rather than poorly code, use `memcpy()` and let the compiler emit efficient code.

```
// int width = *(int *)&header[18];
int width;
memcpy(&width, &header[18], sizeof width);
```

Answer (score 1):

The type that `&` returns is a pointer type. In this case, it is a pointer to the 18th element of the array (17th if you start from the zeroth element).

```
(int *) &header[18];
```

`(int *)` is then casting the pointer type returned by `&` to an `int` pointer, or `int *`.

```
*(int *) &header[18];
```

The `*` then dereferences that `int` pointer, or `int *`, to initialize `width`.

---

Now, to answer your question:
Why the cast?

Because the type of the pointer `header` might not be an `int *`, hence the cast.